# How to draw a vertical line in chart.js2 without label

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js2

I use `chart.js 2.8` and `chartjs-plugin-annotation.js`

I have a bar type chart.

My labels are : `[1.0 - 2.8], [2.8 - 4.6], [6.4 - 8.2], [8.2 - 10.0]`

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: datas
    }]
  },
  options: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: "line",
        mode: "vertical",
        scaleID: "x-axis-0",
        value: "2.8 - 4.6", //value must be equal a label :(
        borderColor: "red",
        label: {
          content: "TODAY",
          enabled: true,
          position: "top"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

I want the vertical line to be drawn at exactly on **2.4** point. But the vertical line can be drawn only at the label value. How can i fix this?